# Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery.ui conflict in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have  a rails app that deals with Bootstrap 2.0. It also uses [jQuery autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox). My application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require rails.validations
//= require jquery.quicksearch
//= require jquery-tablesorter/jquery.metadata
//= require jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter
//= require jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.widgets
//= require jquery-tablesorter/addons/jquery.tablesorter.pager
//= require_tree .
```

The problem is that this way autocomplete works but some buttons don't get class 'active' after the pressing on them. When I put `require bootstrap` after the declaration of query.ui.all like here

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
```

everything happens exactly the opposite way: buttons work but combobox doesn't.
Here is my Gemfile (part of it):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'jquery-tablesorter'    
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'client_side_validations'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue by modifying autocomplete combobox js code by manually adding classes and spans that somehow didn't apply to the element.

Answer (score 2):

always load jquery and jquery ui first since almost every javascript depends on them

Comment: I did. Now, as I described earlier, buttons work but combobox doesn't.

Comment: try updating the boostrap sass first. 
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.0.0'

Comment: also post where are you importing the bootstrap to your css

Comment: Same thing. Bootstrap works but jQuery-ui doesn't.
I import bootstrap in custom.css.scss this way
`@import "bootstrap";`